# How to call function on fragment starting

Tags: android, fragment

Im new at android dev. I have an admob object and I want to show it all pages in my app. So I decided to use fragment.

But I have to call a function to create listview which is use a custom adapter to show custom clas object. There is a problem begins here.

Where can I call my function to find listview and set custom adapter to listview?

**EDIT:**

Here is my code. Its generated from Android Studio Navigation Drawer App.

```
public class Fragment_Main extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        generateListView();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
    }
}
```

Then again, Where can I call function in this code? If I call my function before return it returns null point.

Comment: I guess generateListView() is your method. Is it the one that throws null pointer exception or something else? How does your generateListView() look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function is making an API call, I suggest you to start an async task onCreateView() and once the async task is finished, then set the values to ListView.

Comment: So you say I call an async method in onCreateView() method in my fragment's class? Or I call OnCreateView() in another async task? No, I don't make an Api call. I find the listview and set the adapter the listview.

Comment: Then just add the function call in onCreateView() method of fragment.

Comment: Just to be clear, since you don't have any API call,all you need to do is to call your function from onCreateView() method of your fragment class.

Comment: I update question. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

If your AdMob object is being displayed in a `ListView` within the `Fragment`, you'll need to create your `ListView` in the `onCreateView()` callback of the `Fragment` and set it up appropriately.

Comment: No, I don't want to show an AdMob object in listview. I have a listview in my fragment_main layout and I have a custom adapter to show my object with custom item layout

Comment: It's the same basic concept: create (inflate) your layout and views in the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` method.  You can then create and set your adapter there as well.  Be careful how you load your data, you'll likely need an `AsyncTask` as Yasar suggested or even a `Loader`.